# Bulk modulus of supercrtical air

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, superfluidity, gas

For gaseous state air has bulk modulus of ~pressure, but what about bulk modulus values about the supercritical pressure treshold, are these still pretty much same as the pressure or does this relationship change?

Answer (score 4):

An ideal gas or near-ideal gas such as air at about atmospheric pressure and room temperature has a bulk modulus which is the same as its pressure. That can be readily confirmed by taking the ideal gas equation $PV=nRT$ and substituting it into the equation for the bulk modulus $B=-V \frac{dP}{dV}$.

Now for what P-V equations-of-state does the bulk modulus of a material equal the pressure on it? To find that out set the bulk modulus $B$ equal to $P$ so that you now have the equation $P=-V \frac{dP}{dV}$. A little algebra and an integration will show that the bulk modulus of a material will equal the pressure on it provided that its equation-of-state can be expressed in the form $PV=f(T)$, where f is some arbitrary function of temperature. Note that the ideal gas equation-of-state is a special case of this.

Non-ideal gases such as air in the supercritical regime are described by more complicated equations-of-state than something of the form of $PV=f(T)$. Non-ideal gases may be described by an equation-of-state like:

$P=\frac{nRT}{V-b}+\frac{BnRT}{(V-b)^2}+\frac{CnRT}{(V-b)^3}+...$

where b, B, C,... are constants. So, no, you cannot in general assume that the bulk modulus of a supercritical gas/fluid is equal to its pressure.